# Where does newline come from when using std::cin after std::cout?

Tags: c++

Consider the following simple example

```
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;
    char name[30];        

    cout << "What is your first name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

A sample output of this program is as follows:

```
What is your first name: Bob
Hello Bob
```

This program works as expected, but I don't understand how the output stream knows to go to the next line. I'm basically thinking of two independent streams of information and am confused as to how the output stream knows to go to the next just because it's followed by input. Where does the newline character come from??

Comment: This happens as Ryan Holden says in his answer and is not really preventable. To print text on the same line as the std::cin input was entered, clear the window with `system("cls");` and print again all previous content (given that you can reconstruct it).

Comment: Okay now I'm gonna puke at the mention of system("cls")

Comment: It is preventable by disabling terminal echo (This is a platform-specific operation).  Also it may confuse the user when they can't see their own input.  To echo everything but newline characters, you'd need to also disable line-buffering, process control characters such as backspace, and echo "normal" characters in addition to storing them in a buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output stream doesn't go to the next line.

*You pressed Enter* after typing the name. The terminal has local echo on, which means the characters you enter on the keyboard get echoed to the terminal.

The "Bob" and the newline that you see on the screen are there because you typed them, not because they were sent to `cout` by your program.

If you used a terminal with local echo turned off, or if you piped input from a file containing `Bob`, then the output would look like:

```
What is your first name: Hello Bob
```

Comment: Ahh! I finally get it. Thanks for the response. I understood this answer the first time I read it which was a plus. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The new line, comes from the return character that is used to submit the name while using the cin command. It is simply placed because it is what is originally written by the user while typing "Bob".

Comment: This is correct. If you wish to remove it, replace 'Bob\n' with 'Bob0' where 0 is the null character.

Comment: So does this mean that within the char array "name" there is a return character that comes from the enter key followed by the null character '\0' which implies the end of the string? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @Ockham: No it did not end up in the variable.  But input is line buffered.  The user pressed the ENTER key, and this was echoed by the terminal.

Comment: So when you press enter, a return character is automatically echoed to the terminal and then discarded?

Comment: The function that cin uses to determine when the terminating character of the string should be placed is triggered by the return key. It will recognize the return character, replaces it with the null terminator in the string, however the display, is simply not told to do anything otherwise.

What it does is when you type out the name in the cin line, it will print whatever the user types, you've not told it to do anything different, this includes the new line character, this is why it does not carry over the new line into the variable and reprint it when you cout.

Answer (score 1):

This is what got written to the terminal:

> What is your first name: Bob\nHello Bob\n

This is where it came from (italics from your program writing to stdout, bold from terminal echo):

> *What is your first name:* **Bob\n** *Hello Bob\n*

When the user types (shift)+B,O,B the terminal buffer holds `Bob`.  Since the terminal is line buffered, `stdin` hasn't received any data at all yet.

Now the user presses the Enter key.  This is seen by the line buffered terminal as the end of a line, so `stdin` now sees `Bob\n`.  `operator<<(cin, name)` follows the rules for a formatted input function, discarding leading whitespace and then transferring data to the result until it finds another whitespace.

Now, `name` contains `"Bob"` (no newline here), and the newline character has been used up by `cin` to end this input operation.

Comment: OK, so if I understand you correctly, then std::cin uses the '\n' character to mark the end of the input operation, and then that '\n' character is automatically echoed to the terminal? I just want to make sure I understand what's really happening. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Ockham: No.  Each key is echoed by your terminal.  Because of line buffering, your program (and `cin`) don't receive anything at all when the user types the B-O-B, yet they appear on the screen.  That's terminal echo at work.  So the order is: (shift)+B is pressed, and echoed, and stored in the terminal buffer.  O is pressed, and echoed, and buffered.  B is pressed, and echoed, and buffered.  Enter is pressed, and echoed, and causes the buffer containing `Bob\n` to be delivered to the program.  Then `cin` reads up the the first whitespace, which is the `\n`.  Echo happens before `cin` gets it